# How to improve the speed while using NSURLSessionDownloadTask?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I need to download some images and a video from server:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
for (int i = 0; i < _collectionArr.count; ++i) {

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL_ADDRESS(portNumber,_collectionArr[i])];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
        if (i == _collectionArr.count - 1) {
            [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Done"];
        }

    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
}
```

I found that it is so slow! The speed is about 200K/s and the time with Android is 2/3 less than iPhone.
When I download a mp4 about 4.6M, it takes 15s.

```
2014-11-29 13:46:35.071 testDownload[2105:47825] Begin
2014-11-29 13:46:51.740 testDownload[2105:47825] File downloaded to: file:///Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/259F2CB8-01FD-47C2-A38F-6100A2FF350A/data/Containers/Data/Application/71E553BC-F85D-4BFA-8937-FE9026FDF65C/Documents/VTS_01_audi.mp4
```

But when I using other app to download movies it can be 2M/s. Am I wrong when I use afnetworking ? How it happens and what can I do to deal with it. 
Another question is that I know it's wrong to monitor the last request with  **if (i == _collectionArr.count - 1){[SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Done"];}**  But I don't know the right answer.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Embarrassed. I'm a fresh man and don't know well about block. Sorry. And can you show me what's the right solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I download the movie single but it was the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I know nothing about AFNetworking. Why don't you just use NSURLSession which Apple gives you?

Comment: @Rob It is slow even I download the movie only.

Comment: @magic_9527 Understood. I don't yet see why it would be slower, but I was merely trying to dispense with the suggestion that you might consider submitting these synchronously, because that will just make it much, much slower if doing multiple downloads.

Comment: Aha, I know about thread little.

Comment: The HUD will not dismiss until the mission is done or the request is time out.

Comment: Yeah, there are lots of things to learn, first of all are thread and block. I will trying to find the reason. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. The removal of the HUD when `i` hits `count - 1` is not correct. You actually may remove it before they're all done. If you start two downloads, one huge one and one tiny one, the HUD will be dismissed when the second one finishes, but the other one might not be done yet. These run concurrently, so you have to wait until they're all done, not just when the last submitted one is done.

   One way to do this is to use a dispatch group (which you enter as you submit the requests, leave in the completion block, and then add a dispatch group notification that removes the HUD).
2. You're not doing anything else outside of this code that might be blocking the main thread are you? AFNetworking dispatches its completion blocks to the main queue, and if you block the main thread for anything, it will affect this performance. You could either use Instruments to identify waiting threads, or, for testing purposes only, temporarily change the `completionQueue` of the `manager` to be some custom queue of your own creation.

   For example, before your `for` loop, do something like:

   ```
   manager.completionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.app.netCompletionQueue", NULL);
   ```

   That would take main thread blocking out of the equation (though this strikes me as unlikely unless you're doing something extraordinary in the main thread). Once you confirm this is not the issue, though, comment out that line, because you really do want to use the main thread for your completion blocks.
3. Once you confirm the perf problem is not result on main thread contention issue, I'd suggest doing some benchmarking of alternative techniques (e.g. your own `NSURLSession`, etc.). This could help diagnose whether the problem is AFNetworking, rather than something like simulator vs device performance, caching, etc. Frankly, I find it unlikely that AFNetworking is, itself, the problem, though.